# Why must this function expression use an IIFE in order to produce the results I'm looking for?

Tags: javascript, scope, iife

I'm working my way through Kyle Simpson's 'You Don't Know JS Yet' and I'm having trouble understanding a code example in the Scope and Closures chapter. Specifically, why must I use the IIFE in this function expression in order to get the factorial function to work?

```js
var factorial = (function hideTheCache() {
    var cache = {};
  
  function factorial(x) {
    if(x < 2) return 1;
    
    if(!(x in cache)) {
        
        cache[x] = x * factorial(x-1);
    }
    return cache[x];
  }
  return factorial;

})();

console.log(factorial(6));
```

I thought that if I removed the IIFE from 'hideTheCache()', I would get the same result. This assumption is incorrect. Without the IIFE, the only result I get is a printed out copy of the factorial function declaration itself.

Can someone explain to me what the IIFE is doing to make this function work? And also, what exactly is happening when this function is called *without* the IIFE?

Comment: The IIFE is creating a closure and then returning the inner function `factorial`. Without the immediately invoked part, you must then invoke it yourself. `factorial()(6)`

Comment: Thanks so much @evolutionxbox, that is exactly what I needed. I really appreciate it.